# Google analytic trackEvent not loging to analytic

Tags: android, google-analytics

I used Android's Google Analytic `trackEvent` and tested it using Google's demo code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

// Start the tracker in manual dispatch mode...
  tracker.startNewSession("UA-33260404-1", this);

// ...alternatively, the tracker can be started with a dispatch interval (in seconds).
// tracker.startNewSession("UA-33260404-1", 20, this);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);
createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    tracker.trackEvent(
        "Clicks",  // Category
        "Button",  // Action
        "clicked", // Label
        77);       // Value
  }
});

Button createPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewPageButton);
createPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // Add a Custom Variable to this pageview, with name of "Medium" and value "MobileApp"
    tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Medium", "Mobile App");
    // Track a page view. This is probably the best way to track which parts of your application
    // are being used.
    // E.g.
    // tracker.trackPageView("/help"); to track someone looking at the help screen.
    // tracker.trackPageView("/level2"); to track someone reaching level 2 in a game.
    // tracker.trackPageView("/uploadScreen"); to track someone using an upload screen.
    tracker.trackPageView("/TestActivity");
  }
});
```

I tested it on the mobile device, and I can find base data of example visitor counter, but I cannot see trackPageView("/TestActivity") and trackEvent. I can see tracker.setCustomVar in the report, so my question is how to see the trackEvent. Do I need setting at backstage supporter? Google's documentation is not very detailed on doing this in Android.

edit: I have found the location of the trackPageView and trackEvent, but I have another problem: trackEvent is logging the Clicks, Button, and clicked, but I cannot find the 77 value in the logs. Where do I find the 77?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `tracker.dispatch()`. If you don't set a dispatch interval when you call `tracker.startNewSession()` you need to call `dispatch` at some point, probably in your `onPause` lifecycle method:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#startingTheTracker

Comment: at my app end i add the tracker.dispatch().i can find the value 77 at log,other i can see them

Comment: You have to invoke `setCustomVar` *before* you call `trackPageView` or `trackEvent` otherwise it will not work: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#usingCustomVariables